# How should I report a grammar mistake in the developer Survey results?

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling, survey-2022

There's a grammar mistake in the [Stack Overflow Developer Survey results overview](https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2022/#overview).  The offending sentence is:

> "Younger (under 18) respondents rely most on online resources and are most likely to ***of*** learned from online courses or certifications."

The word *of* should be *have*.

What's the right way for me to report this mistake and have it corrected?

Comment: Probably either posting here, on the blog post at https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/06/22/asked-and-answered-the-results-for-the-2022-developer-survey-are-here, or by using the 'contact us' form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meta is the appropriate place to report such errors.

And this one's been fixed. Thanks for reporting! ^_^